# Matching similar items in a list from user input with Python?

Tags: python, regex, matching

I'm very new to Python, and before anything else, I'd like to apologize if the title is not specific enough, but I don't know another way to word it. Also, apologies if this question is a duplicate. As I said, I really don't know what to look for. Anyways, here's what I want to do:

I have a list like this: `names = ['william shakespeare', 'shakira', 'tom ford', 'tim ford']`

I want the user to be able to input a name, so I'll use `name = input('Enter name:')`, and here's where I get stuck. I want the user to be able to enter a string like `shak` and have the program display `1. William Shakespeare     2. Shakira` or maybe if the user put `ford` have the program show `1. Tom Ford     2. Tim Ford`, and if the user gets more specific, like: `shakespeare` have the program show only `1. William Shakespeare`.

I suppose this is a Regex question, but I find Regex very confusing. I've tried watching several videos to no avail. Any type of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex would be overkill in my opinion. You can use a for loop to iterate through the list. Then using the `in` operator you can check if an entered string is within the string (called a substring). I'll give a simple example.

```
names = ['william shakespeare', 'shakira', 'tom ford', 'tim ford']

substring = input('Enter a substring: ')

for name in names:
    if (substring in name):
        print(name)
```

Since you say you are new to python I refrained from using list comprehensions or anything complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?  If the output isn't quite the way you want it, I expect that you can handle that part later.  The logic finds each applicable name.

```
names = ['william shakespeare', 'shakira', 'tom ford', 'tim ford']
while True:
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    print([entry for entry in names if name in entry])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
list = ['william shakespeare', 'shakira', 'tom ford', 'tim ford']

def get_matching_term(input, list):
    matches = []
    for word in list:
        if input.lower() in word.lower():
            matches.append(word)
    return matches

thing_to_match = raw_input("Enter name to find:")
matches = get_matching_term(thing_to_match, list)

for idx, match in enumerate(matches):
    print("Match #" + str((idx + 1)) + ": " + match)
```

Then you can invoke it like such.

```
python test.py
Enter name to find: shak
Match #1: william shakespeare
Match #2: shakira
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is very useful, but this particular example doesn't require a regex. Using string.lower() on both strings makes this case insensitive.

```
i=0
For item in names:
  if name.lower() in item.lower():
    i++
    print str(i) + '. ' + item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['william shakespeare', 'shakira', 'tom ford', 'tim ford']

search = str(input("Please enter search term  "))

ref = list(search.lower()) # this is your search text

out = []

count = 1

ind = 0


for i in names: # loops over your list

        #print () #take the hash out to see what is i

        for j in list(i.lower()): # list converts your variable into a list ie shakira = ['s','h'..]

            if j == ref[ind]:
                ind += 1
            else:
                ind = 0  

            if ind == len(ref): #ind is gonna go over each index in ref, if ind = the length of your 
        # search text then you have found a match

                out.append(i)
                ind = 0
                break


if len(out) == 0:
    out.append(" Nothing found ")
    count = 0

for i in out:
    print ("{}. {}".format(count,i), end = "\t\t")
    count += 1
```

Okay! there are a lot of ways to do this, tried to make it as simple as possible.
Flaws: If there are two names which are similar, eg Will and William and you search for will, you will get both names. If you search for william it will give you Willaim only. Also the design is not that efficient, two for loops, basically it running linear to the number of letters in the list, (total letters.) See how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_list = [{"First_Name": "Sam", "Last_Name": "John", "Age": 24},
            {"First_Name": "Martin", "Last_Name": "Lukas", "Age": 34},
            {"First_Name": "Jeff", "Last_Name": "Mark", "Age": 44},
            {"First_Name": "Jones", "Last_Name": "alfred", "Age": 54}]

getdetails = input("Name: ")

for i in range(len(dict_list)):
    if (getdetails in dict_list[i]["First_Name"]):
        print(f'Details are  {dict_list[i]}')

$$$$$$$ output $$$$$$

Name: Jeff
Details are  {'First_Name': 'Jeff', 'Last_Name': 'Mark', 'Age': 44}

Process finished with exit code 0
```